# Is Deadlock recovery possible in MultiThread programming?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, operating-system, deadlock

Process has some 10 threads and all 10 threads entered DEADLOCK state( assume all are waiting for Mutex variable ).

How can you free process(threads) from DEADLOCK state ? . 
Is there any way to kill lower priority thread ?( in Multi process case we can kill lower priority process when all processes in deadlock state).

Can we attach that deadlocked process to the debugger and assign proper value to the Mutex variable ( assume all the threads are waiting on a mutex variable MUT but it is value is 0 and can we assign MUT value to 1 through debugger ) .

Comment: Yes, it's possible - design and implement everything threading-related with extreme care and pray ;)

Comment: It *may* be possible, but it's heavily implementation-dependent. For the general case which you seem to ask about, the most specific answer is "maybe". Give us some more detail, perhaps? (also, your title is asking about deadlock *prevention*, whereas body is asking about *resolution* - by analogy, "prevent a car crash" is a very different problem than "recover from a car crash"; which one do you want?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding another answer because I don't agree with the solutions proposed by cHao earlier - the analysis is fine.

First, why I disagree with the two solutions offered:

> Reduce contention

Contention doesn't lead to deadlocks. It just causes poor performance. Deadlock means *no* performance whatsoever. Therefore, reducing contention does not solve deadlocks.

> timeout on mutex.

A mutex protects a resource, and a thread locks the mutex because it needs the resource. With a timeout, you won't be able to acquire the resource, and your thread fails. Does it solve the deadlock problem? Only if the failing thread releases another resource that was blocking the other threads.

But in that case, there's a much better solution. Mutexes should have a partial ordering. If there is at least one thread that can both mutex A and B, you should decide whether A or B is acquired first, and then *stick with that*. This must be a transitive order: if you lock A before B, and B before C, then obviously you must lock A before C.

This is a perfect solution to deadlocks. Look back at the timeout example: it only works if the thread that times out waiting on A then releases its lock on B, to release another thread that was waiting on B. In the most simple case, that other thread was itself directly locking A. Thus, the mutexes A and B are not properly ordered. You should have consistently locked either A or B first.

The timeout case could also be the result of a cyclic order problem; one thread locks A then B, another B then C, and a third C then A, with the deadlock happening when each thread owns one lock. The solution again is the same; order the locks.

Alternatively said, mutex lock orders can be described by a directed graph. If a thread locks A before B, there's an arc from A to B. Deadlocks appear if the directed graph is cyclic, and then the arcs of that cycle are the deadlocked threads.

This theory can be a bit complex, but there are some simple insights to be found. For instance, from the graph theory, we know that trees are acyclic graphs. Hence, neither "leaf mutexes" (those that are always locked *last*) nor "root mutexes" (those that are always locked *first*) can cause deadlocks. Leaf mutexes are excluded because no thread ever blocks holding them, and root mutexes are excluded because the thread that holds them will be able to lock all subsequent mutexes in due time.

Comment: I know the thread Id.How can I kill that thread ? . If I kill that thread, will it abort entire process ( which has multiple threads)

Comment: @siva: Killing one thread is no solution to deadlock. You have interdependent threads (they share resources, else they didn't deadlock). If you kill one, you'd better kill all of them. The others cannot reliably proceed. Now, it is _theoretically_ possible that the group of deadlocked threads were otherwise isolated and your process can recover from losing all those threads. In practice, you log the error and terminate the entire process instead of just one thread.

Answer (score 5):

If every thread in the app is waiting on every other, and none are set to time out, you're rather screwed.  You might be able to run the app in a debugger or something, but locks are generally acquired for a reason -- and manually forcing a mutex to be owned by a thread that didn't legitimately acquire it can cause some big problems (the thread that previously owned it is still going to try and release it, the results of which can be unpredictable if the mutex is unexpectedly yanked away.  Could cause an unexpected exception, could cause the mutex to be unlocked while still in use.)  Anyway it defeats the whole purpose of mutexes, so you're just covering up a much bigger problem.

There are two common solutions:

- Instead of having threads wait forever, set a timeout.  This is slightly harder to do in languages like Java that embed mutexes into the language via `synchronized` or `lock` blocks, but it's almost always possible.  If you time out waiting on the lock, release all the locks/mutexes you had and try later.
- Better, but potentially much more complex, is to figure out why everything's fighting for the resource and remove that contention.  If you must lock, lock consistently.  But if there's 10 threads blocking on a single mutex, that could be a clue either that your operations are badly chunked (ie: that your threads are doing too much or too little at once before trying to acquire a lock), or that there's unnecessary locking going on.  Don't lock unless you have to.  Some synchronization could be obviated by using collections and algorithms specifically designed to be "lock-free" while still offering thread-safety.

Comment: But, how would the system come to the same state(without deadlock) after releasing all the locks/mutexes ?

Comment: @KarthikBalaguru:  Without some help, *it wouldn't*.  Any changes already made have been made, and typically won't be reverted on their own.  You'd have to use a two-phase / transactional mechanism (recording the changes temporarily, and committing all at once only on successful completion), or remember enough info to undo the changes yourself before releasing the lock that was synchronizing them.